# Migrating an existing spring jersey servlet2.5, Jersey2.3 webapp to springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Evaluating to port an existing mid to large sized multi module JEE application,  this consists servlet 2.5, Jersey for rest and Spring 3.2.9 (JDK8, Maven 3. currently we build a war file and deploy it on to aws. My objective for this exercise is to be able to use spring-boot to create a self contained executable jar that can be installed on AWS and this would help us just run on cloud with java -jar

Is it possible to use spring boot considering the project is not using spring-web module, it is more traditional Servlet2.5 statically declaring all servlets and filters in web.xml

which approach is better, adding spring boot as a parent or dependency.

Any experience and info our senior spring community members have in this kind of migration.

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely possible to do even if you're not using Spring Web MVC.

You can use `spring-boot-starter-parent` [like a BOM POM, so you can import its dependencies without having to change your POM's parent](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent).

Take a look at the [Spring Boot documentation for migrating a `web.xml` application to Spring Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-convert-an-existing-application-to-spring-boot).  The main points here for traditionally deployed servlets and filters are:

> A `@Bean` of type `Servlet` or `ServletRegistrationBean` installs that bean
>   in the container as if it was a `<servlet/>` and `<servlet-mapping/>` in
>   `web.xml`.
>
> A `@Bean` of type `Filter` or `FilterRegistrationBean` behaves
>   similarly (like a `<filter/>` and `<filter-mapping/>`.